# DataSnapshot not working to create custom objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is I'm trying to make the messageAdapter to show the messages in the database on the recycleView in MessageActvity and here is the method code (in short) for doing that:

**case-1**

```
private void readMessages(final String myID, final String userID, final String imageURL) {
    mChat = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mChat.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                assert chat != null;
                if ( chat.getSender().equals(myID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(userID) ||
                     chat.getSender().equals(userID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(myID)) {
                    mChat.add(chat) ;
                }

                messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChat, imageURL);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }

    });
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

the thing is that method is working perfectly well when defining the Chat chat manually like that:

**case-2**

```
Chat chat = new Chat(sender, receiver, "hi there");
```

and it even show the message "hi there" X amount of times (X = the number of messages in the database).

I even tried to do something like that to use snapshot:

**case-3**

```
 String sender = snapshot.child("sender").getValue()).toString();
 String receiver = snapshot.child("receiver").getValue()).toString();
 String message = snapshot.child("message").getValue()).toString();
            Chat chat = new Chat(sender,receiver,message);
```

but still, it does not work. The result is always crashing (except for the manually defined case-**2**, it works).

I tried changing the condition of the if statement as:

**case-4**

```
if (chat.getSender() != null && chat.getReceiver() != null && chat.getSender().equals(myID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(userID) ||
    chat.getSender() != null && chat.getReceiver() != null && chat.getSender().equals(userID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(myID)) {
                    mChat.add(chat) ;
    }
```

and after doing that the app is no longer crushing because the if statement does not work... I think what crushes the app is that

```
chat.getSender() == null && chat.getReceiver == null
```

and when the if statement begin checking the condition it crushes.

**EDIT-updated:** after experimenting with log.v it turns out that the values returned from the datasnapshot and the getter methods is null!. Here is the code

```
if (chat.getSender() == null){
         Log.v("MessageActivity", "sender is null: " + chat.getSender());
}
if (chat.getReceiver() == null) {
         Log.v("MessageActivity", "receiver is null: " + chat.getReceiver());
}
```

*updated*

```
Log.v("MessageActivity", "snapshot: " +snapshot );
Log.v("MessageActivity", "chat variables: " + chat.getMessage() + ", " + chat.getReceiver() + ", " + chat.getSender() );
Log.v("MessageActivity", "mchat: " + mChat);
```

Consol:

```
2020-06-10 21:17:44.578 29735-29735/com.example.android.chattingapp V/MessageActivity: sender is null: null
2020-06-10 21:17:44.578 29735-29735/com.example.android.chattingapp V/MessageActivity: receiver is null: null

//updated
snapshot: DataSnapshot { key = -M9TzQuBbYfv-OhJgRyR, value = {message: =hahah, sender: =DuD8LfwlreNjByrptsh4zgXDQie2, receiver: =hFpPOfnvsKbJiZtfCBoGyDPnQXy2} }
chat variables: null, null, null
mchat: []
```

and when trying to debug the code it seems that snapshot has the data as shown in this image [The debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5k0G.png).

**Edit-2:** I included an image for the firebase database data [Database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bj1s.png)

**Edit-3: my Chat class**

```
public class Chat{

private String sender;
private String receiver;
private String message;

public Chat(String message, String sender, String receiver) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.message = message;
}

public Chat(){

}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getReceiver() {
    return receiver;
}

public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

Comment: You are creating multiple adapters inside your for-loop when you do setAdapter , take a look at that line, you should be only creating one instance of the adapter with the data

Comment: @GastónSaillén tried to move the adapter and setAdapter out of the for loop. Nothing changed the app still crashing with the same error. But thank you for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Now try to:

1. change `onDataChange()` callback, assign the adapter and
   recyclerView aftre you build the full data (outside the for loop)
2. Check if `dataSnapshot.exits()` is true before proceeding

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       if (!dataSnapshot.exits())
           return;

       mChat.clear();
       for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

           assert chat != null;
           if ( chat.getSender().equals(myID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(userID) ||
                chat.getSender().equals(userID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(myID)) {
               mChat.add(chat) ;
           }

       }

       messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChat, imageURL);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
   }
   ```

Comment: Zain. Its not the adapter that is the problem. His database value won't map to his POJO class

Comment: The condition is false, which means that the dataSnapshot does exist. and lead for the  for loop to work and the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your database its like this:

```
Chats 
  Hhokjvvvcccxddtyiii
          sender=someone
          receiver = some1
          message = hello
```

You missed that each child has an **Id** so u can't just do:

```
 Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
```

Values will be null, thats why this;

```
 String sender = snapshot.child("sender").getValue()).toString();
 String receiver = snapshot.child("receiver").getValue()).toString();
 String message = snapshot.child("message").getValue()).toString();
```

Worked for u.

**Edit** 
Do:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");
   Query query = ref.orderByKey();

   query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
       {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mChat.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

            assert chat != null;
            if ( chat.getSender().equals(myID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(userID) ||
                 chat.getSender().equals(userID) &&  chat.getReceiver().equals(myID)) {
                mChat.add(chat) ;
            }


        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError 
    databaseError) {
    }

});
```

Comment: I edit the question to include an image for the database. I think it's good. If not, please correct me. Also, that method you mentioned in your answer (the code I used in the question) didn't work for me :(

Comment: thank you for your time, it still doesn't work though (the same error).The snapshot variable has all the data but the chat variable is null. Feeling bad right now.

Comment: Can I see your Chat class??

Comment: Just edited the question and included the Chat class

Comment: and tried to put new conditions in the if statement and the app is not crushing anymore I added it in a case-4 (in the question).

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you for everyone who tried to help.

After so many time and research, I found the solution to my problem and it turns out that the readMessage method was working just fine from the beginning :)

The error was in the send message method (which was working perfectly well by the way!).

The original code was like this:

```
private void sendMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message) {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender: ", sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver: ", receiver);
    hashMap.put("message: ", message);

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
}
```

and the correct code is:

```
private void sendMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
    hashMap.put("message", message);

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
}
```

and if you haven't noticed the difference, it's in the hashMap.put (sender: ), (receiver: ) and (message: ).